# Website loses mobile-friendliness when loaded in frame

Tags: html, css, mobile-chrome

I have a page on my website in which I'm loading a purpose-built WIX marketing site inside a `frame` thusly:

```
<html><frameset cols='100%'><frame src='https://michael3557.wixsite.com/truckercert'></frameset></html>
```

On a pc/laptop, everything looks fine and as expected. But on a phone, the "mobile-friendliness" of the wix page is gone, and a super-narrow, unfriendly page displays.

Yet if you hit the [wix link shown above](https://michael3557.wixsite.com/truckercert) directly (not inside a frame) on a phone's browser, it does look fine and mobile-friendly.

Why does my page lose its mobile-friendly nature just because it's loaded inside a frame? And how can I solve this?

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here. https://blog.theodo.com/2018/01/responsive-iframes-css-trick/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser determines the `viewport` settings from the top-level document.

The frame HTML has no `<meta>` tag setting the `viewport`.

The page inside the frame is not the top-level document so its `<meta>` `viewport` data is ignored.

Comment: Thanks...so how can I solve this? Can i place those meta properties up at the frameset level? If so, how?

Comment: "Can i place those meta properties up at the frameset level?" — Yes.

Comment: Copy what? Paste where? Are you saying I should add a `head` element into my frameset and add the meta properties there?

Comment: You should put the complete solution in your answer: `<html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'></head><frameset cols='100%'><frame src='https://michael3557.wixsite.com/truckercert'></frameset></html>`